# How do I output an individual eqn described equation to a .ps or .eps?

Tags: groff, postscript, roff

I would like to reuse the output from eqn to get PS or EPS files which contains just the equation and not a complete A4 with the equation.

If I try:

```
$ cat test.eqn
.EQ
For ~ y=1 ~ -> ~ L( y hat , y) = -log( y hat ) ~ -> ~ if ~ y hat approx 1 ~ then ~ L( y hat , y ) approx 0
.EN
$ cat test.eqn | eqn | groff -Tps > test.ps
```

I get `test.ps` generated and I can see the equation properly formatted, but it is displayed as part of a complete page (either A4 or letter size).

What shall be done to get just a document which contains just the required size to contain the equation? i.e. the whole page would had been cropped to the necessary space to contain the equation.

Additionally, if I try to use `troff` instead of `groff` I can not manage to get PS code, why? (FreeBSD 12).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pipe the output through `eps2eps` to get an EPS file:

```
eqn test.eqn | groff -Tps | eps2eps - test.eps
```